# Content Property in EPUB 2

Tags: epub, css

I am working with EPUB 2 specifications and I am trying to determine whether or not the content property is supported in EPUB2.  I know that it is for EPUB 3 - http://www.idpf.org/accessibility/guidelines/content/style/reference.php#css025-css21

I am using the content property to generate txt break symbols e.g. "***"

I can see them in my web browser but they are not showing up on my devices or previewers.  There is just a blank space with no asterisks.

`.TXBDINGBATS {
    font-family: SAT_disp_bold;`

```
font-size:1.05em;
line-height: 1.4em;

text-align: center;
margin: .5em 0 .5em -1.3em;
text-indent: 0;

content: "\2217 \a0 \a0 \a0 \a0 \a0 \2217 \a0 \a0 \a0 \a0 \a0 \2217";
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind the following, which is at the top of the page that you linked to: "EPUB 3 reading systems that visually render content are expected to provide support for the CSS properties listed on this page, but support is not required." In practice, I would be surprised to find any major reading systems, with the possible exception of iBooks, that support `content`, but I have not done any testing to be able to say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

EPUB 2 specifies `content` as supported property in the [list of CSS properties](http://www.idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPS_2.0.1_draft.htm#Section3.3).

However, it is based on CSS 2.1, where the `content` property is allowed only for `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements. As the linked EPUB 3 spec shows (by linking to CSS 2.1), the same restriction applies in EPUB 3.

Thus, the code in the question won’t work, to the extent that it relies on the `content` property. Moving the declaration to apply to a pseudo-element, if applicable, should work in conforming software:

```
.TXBDINGBATS:before {
  content: "\2217 \a0 \a0 \a0 \a0 \a0 \2217 \a0 \a0 \a0 \a0 \a0 \2217";
}
```